# My Megaparsec parser gets stuck and ghci debugging isn't helping either

Tags: parsing, haskell, megaparsec

I have worked through [this Megaparsec tutorial](https://markkarpov.com/megaparsec/parsing-simple-imperative-language.html) and am trying now to write my own parser based on that. I want so write a simple parser for a made-up assembly language:

```
Label: lda $0ffe
       sta %10100110
       push $01, $02, $03
```

This are the simple data types I'm using:

```
-- Syntax.hs
module Syntax where

import  Data.Int

-- |A program is made up of one or more source lines
type Program = [SourceLine]

data SourceLine = SourceLine
    { label :: Maybe String     -- ^ Each line may contain a label
    , instr :: Maybe String     -- ^ This can either be an opcode or an assembler directive
    , operand :: Maybe String   -- ^ The opcode/instruction may need operand(s)
    }
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Here's the code of the parser:

```
--Parser.hs
module Parser where

import Syntax

import Control.Applicative (empty)
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Monad.Combinators.Expr
-- import Data.Scientific (toRealFloat)
import Data.Void
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import qualified Text.Megaparsec.Char.Lexer as L

type Parser = Parsec Void String

-- | Parse a single source code line
sourceline :: Parser SourceLine
sourceline = do
    l <- optional labelfield
    i <- optional instrfield
    o <- optional oprfield
    return $ SourceLine l i o

-- TODO: forbid double underscores
-- | Parse the label field of a source line
labelfield :: Parser String
labelfield = (lexeme . try) $ do
    l <- identifier
    symbol ":"
    return l

-- TODO: parse assembler directives starting with an elipse (.)
-- | Parse the instruction field of a source line
instrfield :: Parser String
instrfield = (lexeme . try) $ do
    i <- some letterChar
    return i

-- | Parse the operand field of a source line
oprfield :: Parser String
oprfield = (lexeme . try) $ do
    o <- try identifier
         <|> datalist
         <|> number
    return o

-- | Parses a legal identifier; identifiers must start with a letter
--   and my contain underscores or numbers
identifier :: Parser String
identifier = ((:) <$> letterChar <*> many (alphaNumChar <|> char '_'))

-- | Parse a list of values separated by commas (,)
datalist :: Parser String
datalist = do
    x <- some datalist'
    y <- number
    return $ filter (/='\n') $ unlines x ++ y

datalist' :: Parser String
datalist' = try ((++) <$> number <*> (symbol ","))

-- | Parse numbers
number :: Parser String
number = try binnumber
         <|> decnumber
         <|> hexnumber

binnumber :: Parser String
binnumber = lexeme ((:) <$> char '%' <*> (some $ binDigitChar))

decnumber :: Parser String
decnumber = lexeme $ some digitChar

hexnumber :: Parser String
hexnumber = lexeme ((:) <$> char '$' <*> (some $ hexDigitChar))

----- Helper Function ----------------------------------------------------------
lineComment :: Parser ()
lineComment = L.skipLineComment "#"

-- eats all whitespace and newline
scn :: Parser ()
scn = L.space space1 lineComment empty

-- eats all whitespace but newline
sc :: Parser ()
sc = L.space (void $ takeWhile1P Nothing f) lineComment empty
  where
    f x = x == ' ' || x == '\t'

lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme = L.lexeme sc

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol = L.symbol sc

-- this is giving me trouble
prog :: Parser Program
prog = between scn eof (sepEndBy sourceline scn)
```

I've put the function that is giving me trouble. I've written some tests for these functions, here's the tests:

```
-- file Spec.hs
import Syntax
import Parser

import Text.Megaparsec

import Test.Hspec
import Test.Hspec.Megaparsec
import Test.QuickCheck
import Control.Exception (evaluate)

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
    describe "Label parsing" $ do
        it "Parse empty label field" $
            parse sourceline "" " " `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing Nothing Nothing
        it "Parse single character lower-case label" $
            parse sourceline "" "x:" `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "x") Nothing Nothing
        it "Parse multi-character label" $
            parse sourceline "" "label:" `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "label") Nothing Nothing
        it "Parse multi-character label with trailing whitespace" $
            parse sourceline "" "label:   " `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "label") Nothing Nothing
        it "Parse label with underscore" $
            parse sourceline "" "la_bel:   " `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "la_bel") Nothing Nothing
        it "Parse label with underscores and numbers" $
            parse sourceline "" "l4_b3l:   " `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "l4_b3l") Nothing Nothing

    describe "Label and opcode parsing" $ do
        it "Parse line with label and opcode" $
            parse sourceline "" "label: lda" `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "label") (Just "lda") Nothing
        it "Parse line opcode only" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda" `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") Nothing

    describe "Opcodes and operands parsing" $ do
        it "Parse an opcode with symbol operand" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda label_2" `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "label_2")
        it "Parse an opcode with binary operand" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda %01101" `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "%01101")
        it "Parse an opcode with decimal operand" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda 1234" `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "1234")
        it "Parse an opcode with hexdecimal operand" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda $affe34" `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "$affe34")
        it "Parse a labeled opcode with symbol operand" $
            parse sourceline "" "label: lda label_2" `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "label") (Just "lda") (Just "label_2")
        it "Parse a labeled opcode with binary operand" $
            parse sourceline "" "labe_l: lda %01101" `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "labe_l") (Just "lda") (Just "%01101")
        it "Parse a labeled opcode with decimal operand" $
            parse sourceline "" "label_2: lda 1234" `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "label_2") (Just "lda") (Just "1234")
        it "Parse a labeled opcode with hexdecimal operand" $
            parse sourceline "" "l4b3l: lda $affe34" `shouldParse` SourceLine (Just "l4b3l") (Just "lda") (Just "$affe34")

    describe "Operand parsing" $ do
        it "Parse a value/data list with decimal values" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda 12,23,23,43  " `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "12,23,23,43")
        it "Parse a value/data list with binary values" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda %101,%111,%000,%001  " `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "%101,%111,%000,%001")
        it "Parse a value/data list with hexdecimal values" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda $101,$affe,$AfF3,$c3D4  " `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "$101,$affe,$AfF3,$c3D4")
        it "Parse a value/data list with spaces" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda $101, $affe , $AfF3,$c3D4" `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "$101,$affe,$AfF3,$c3D4")
        it "Parse a value/data list with spaces and mixed values" $
            parse sourceline "" "lda %101, 1234 , $AfF3,$c3D4" `shouldParse` SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "%101,1234,$AfF3,$c3D4")

    -- describe "Parse multiple lines" $ do
    --     it "Parse a 3-line program" $
    --         parse prog "" "label1: \n  lda $10\nsta %10011001" `shouldParse` [SourceLine (Just "label1") Nothing Nothing,
    --                                                                           SourceLine Nothing (Just "lda") (Just "$10"),
    --                                                                           SourceLine Nothing (Just "sta") (Just "%10011001")]
```

As usual with assembly files, I want to parse the source code line by line. All the tests above pass, except for the out-commented one. Running `prog` in `ghci` with `parseTest` yields the same result, it returns no result and crashes eventually:

```
*Main Parser Syntax Text.Megaparsec> parseTest sourceline "lda $10 # comment ignored"
SourceLine {label = Nothing, instr = Just "lda", operand = Just "$10"}
*Main Parser Syntax Text.Megaparsec> parseTest prog "lda $10\nsta %1010"
-- crashes
```

I'm assuming that I am somehow ab-/overusing `lexeme` in my code to remove trailing whitespace from the parsed strings. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sepEndBy sourceline scn` will keep iterating as long as it can get the `sourceLine` and `scn` parsers to match.  However, both of those parsers can complete successfully without consuming any input, so they will always match.  Since all of the branches of `sourceLine` have a `try`, any parse error will cause the parser to back off and just match an infinite number of empty source lines.  Even without a parse error, reaching eof will produce an infinite number of source lines.